# NextJS - Change all redirects from 308 to 301

Tags: redirect, next.js, next.js13, http-status-code-301

I have a requirement from a customer SEO to redirect all pages from 308 to 301. Project is developed in NextJS 13 with page folder. I've handled most of the cases (old pages to new pages after migration) in middleware.ts using

`return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(address.destination), { status: 301 });`

General page structure is following: xyz.com/offer/:brand/:model/

The problem is that when user enters `xyz.com//offer` or `xyz.com///offer` it redirects to `xyz.com/offer` with 308 code.

I've also tried using redirects inside next config:

```
        return [
            {
                source: '/offer/',
                destination: '/offer',
                statusCode: 301,
            },
        ];
    }
```

But its impossible to predict all cases with multiple slashes + it doesn't work as inteded (redirection with 301 doesn't happen).

Is is any way in next to set all inner redirects to 301?

Answer (score 0):

Update your next.config.js to include a custom server rewrite rule for handling redirects:

// next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      // Redirect all routes with multiple slashes to the clean version with 301 status code
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        destination: '/:path*',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Comment: Rewrites does not accept `permanent`, redirects do - but after an implementation in redirects it keeps in infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop redirect on 308 then you disable 2 options in your next.config.ts/mjs/js file

```
const nextConfig = {
  trailingSlash: false, // MAKE THIS FALSE because this redirect is on 308.
  images: { unoptimized: true },
  reactStrictMode: false,
  cacheMaxMemorySize: 0
  permanent: false, // MAKE THIS OPTION FALSE. FOR REDIRECT
}
```